# How to get Entity name from named sql queries by query name (Java)?

Tags: hibernate

I use Hibernate v3.3.
I need to find *Entity name* in *named sql queries* by *query name*.
I have found that **SessionFactory** contains field **namedSqlQueries**, which contains **Map query name -> NamedSqlQueryDefinition**.
**NamedSqlQueryDefinition** contains **queryReturns**, **queryReturns** contains field **returnEntityName** with *Entity name*.
Also in session **getNamedQuery** method returns the object, which contains **queryReturns** filed with **returnEntityName**, but
method **getReturnTypes** throws "not yet implemented for SQL queries" exception.

So, how do I get *Entity name* by *query name*?

Thanks!